# Run my Java program outside Eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

I want to Run my Java program outside Eclipse ,it work on eclipse great with swing interface , can i make it .exe or an api thats work on windows???

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a [Runnable jar file](http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/basics/runnable-jar.jspx).

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

You can make a batch file for your application than a .exe.